# Can not upgrade Ubuntu server to 13.04 using command line

Tags: server, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade ubuntu server from 12.10 to 13.04 using command line.

I get the follow error when I do this command "sudo do-release-upgrade -d":

```
 $ sudo do-release-upgrade -d
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/do-release-upgrade", line 145, in <module>
    fetcher.run_options += ["--mode=%s" % options.mode,
AttributeError: type object 'DistUpgradeFetcherCore' has no attribute 'run_options'
```

Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The `-d` switch is not required in this case. At the time of the question, 13.04 was stable not development. The `-d` switch indicates to `do-release-upgrade` to install the latest development version, but at the time no distribution was on *development*. A normal `sudo do-release-upgrade` will upgrade your system.